# Can't RDP to domain member as a domain user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I've added a new domain user - who is a member of the "Remote Desktop Users" group, but they are unable to log in to a domain member.

The error in event viewer is

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       myaccount@mydomain.local
    Account Domain:

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Domain sid inconsistent.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000019b

The client just gets "credentials did not work"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried logging in using format DOMAIN\username as well?  Verified that the user is a member of the local "Remote Desktop Users" group on the domain member they are logging into (ie not the Domain's Remote Desktop Users Group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they new virtual machines, poorly sysprepped? You could be running into this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2rds/thread/afe39595-148d-4ab7-b283-543af749f6f4

I did deploy virtual machines from a poorly configured template and ran into this problem straight away, and reinstalled everything from scratch and it worked. But I'm not convinced about the explanation because of [Mark Russinovich from SysInternals](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx)'s explanation on why duplicate SIDs ought not to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue related to trust between the server the your domain... As troubleshooting steps try these

- Try creating a new user in AD and add the user to remote desktop users, then try to logon using that account.
- unjoin this server from domain and rejoin it.